# When is the $I$-Bessel function an algebraic integer?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, bessel-functions

Is there any way to determine if the [$I$-Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) $I_{a}(x)$ is an algebraic integer whenever $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x$ is an algebraic integer?

I have tried to search other papers on this topic, but almost all of them are analytic results on $I_{a}(x)$. At least a push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could see if there is literature on the similar question for simpler special functions. Again you will likely see almost entirely analytic results, but you might have slightly more luck with the expanded pool of special functions.

Comment: Tangentially related: Siegel shows in *Über einige Anwendungen diophantischer Approximationen* (available in English as *On Some Applications of Diophantine Approximations*, edited by Zannier) that zeros of $J_\nu(x)$ and $J'_\nu(x)$ are transcendental for rational $\nu$, and (more importantly for this question) $J'_\nu(x) / J_\nu(x)$ is transcendental for all rational $\nu$ and algebraic $x$.

Comment: There is some discussion of Bessel functions vis-a-vis transcendence in Waldschmidt, Irrationality and transcendence of values of special functions, https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/ValuesSpecialFunctionsICSFA2016.pdf

Comment: Having now gone and dug it up, the same Siegel result also shows that $J_0(x)$ is never algebraic for $x \neq 0$ algebraic.

Comment: @prets This is kind of surprising to me. If it fails for $k = 0$ then I have doubts about higher $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Recently [Fonseca](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/jardimdafons/papers/poincare.pdf) has shown that coefficients of negatively-indexed Poincare series are rational (given some conditions on their corresponding cusp forms under a certain differential operator), and those coefficients all have $I$-Bessel functions in them with natural number index and rational-algebraic integers as inputs.

Comment: Have you had a look at Waldschmidt, Freddie?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I did, though not extensively. Section 2 had the juiciest material it seemed, stating results about quotients of Bessel functions, though I cannot find access to the cited article by Sury. As Robert Israel points out below, this gives a partial answer somewhat.

Answer (score 2):

For example, $I_1(2)/I_0(2)$ is known to be transcendental (Siegel 1929).  Therefore $I_1(2)$ and $I_0(2)$ can't both be algebraic numbers.